# Incompatible library version for libswiftCore.dylib after integrating Realm Swift

Tags: ios, swift2, realm

After installing Realm Swift, I see the following error when running my test program from within Xcode:

> dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftCore.dylib
>    Referenced from: /Users/(*****)/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/*****/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/*****/My.app/Frameworks/RealmSwift.framework/RealmSwift
>    Reason: Incompatible library version: RealmSwift requires version 1.0.0 or later, but libswiftCore.dylib provides version 0.0.0

I have tried:

- Cleaning the build folder
- Restarting Xcode
- Enabling the *Embedded Content Contains Swift Code* build setting.

I am using Xcode 7.2.1 with Swift 2.1.1, and am integrating Realm using its dynamic Framework.

Comment: Did you perform accurate all steps described at the [realm installation section](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#installation-swift-211)?

Comment: Which version of Realm Swift are you using?

Comment: maybe put a demo project in github to help people understand the problem and better help you.

Comment: @Azat Thanks. I'll check again.

Comment: @bdash Thanks. version 0.98.0

Comment: @zhaow Thanks. I'll try.

Comment: @HiroyukiKikuchi there is a version 0.98.6, I would like to recommend you use the latest one

Answer (score 2):

Apple states that you can't mix and match binaries built with different versions of Swift: https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=2

So you have two choices:

1. Build Realm Swift from source following the instructions found at https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#installation
2. Use a prebuilt version of Realm Swift built with the same version of Swift as your project. 0.98.5 was the last version built with Swift 2.1.1: https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/releases/tag/v0.98.5. 0.98.6 and later are built with Swift 2.2.

Comment: Thanks and sorry for my late reply. I've fixed it now after updating Xcode to 7.3 with Swift 2.2 & RealmSwift 0.98.6.